# Microsoft Authenticator app is not working when connected to Mobile Data but with WIFI it is working

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

We are using Microsoft Azure Authentication for one of our web apps. Since yesterday, one of my boss's phone Authenticator app is not working when he is connected to Mobile data during Authentication but when connected to WIFI it is working (I already checked he has mobile data). He is using iPhone XS. Can you guys guide me on this? [image]

Comment: Could be lots of things, but given it's working on wifi and not mobile data suggests (a) it's not Azure that's the problem and (b) the mobile network is a probable cause. Can you try it on another handset that's on a different network? Does the handset connect to websites ok when on mobile data?

Comment: Yes, when on mobile data handsets are connecting to normal websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found that the issue is caused because the user has **disabled the mobile data for the App (only)**. That is why when I tried to check whether the internet is working in the browser, it actually works.